Regex with even instances of ab and ba
I am trying to write a regex to match strings with even instances of ab and ba with only the alphabet of {a,b}.
I am trying to do so with only | and * operators. I think it has something to do with the number of times I switch letters needing to be even.
Ex: aba is accepted (1 ab and 1 ba). It switches between characters twice.
aaaa is accepted as it has 0 instances of ab and ba and switches characters 0 times.
I am really struggling to generate the regex.
I tried regexes like (a*b*a*)|(b*a*b*) and a few others but I cannot seem to solve it.

The description of what you want is not clear. Please [edit] the question to show some example of valid and of invalid strings.

But what about abab it has ab 2 times and ba 1 time...

In modern regex, maybe like this demo (which is generated from @ruakh's answer).

If a string contains only a's and b's, then the number of occurrences of ab will be equal to the number of occurrences of ba if and only if it starts and ends with the same letter.
So you can write: a(a|b)*a|b(a|b)*b

I understood the question after reading your answer. :D
